# How to change the size of the iteration segment (Python(

Tags: python, size, iteration

I've been recently trying to iterate over a webpages source using a for loop. This script detects the webpage, finds the keywords and correctly identifies the number of instances.

However there are some lines it iterates over that are bigger than 128 characters and so it fragments them, making things more difficult for data extraction and generally it looks unclean.

I have been trying to find a way to increase this number to say, 500 (or 512) characters but have since failed. If anyone knows of a way to do this (it's probably really simple). It would be greatly appreciated.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.trademe.co.nz/Browse/SearchResults.aspx?sort_order=price_desc&searchString=punching+bag&rptpath=all&type=Search&searchType=all&generalSearch_keypresses=12&generalSearch_suggested=0&searchregion=16')

count = 0
for x in r:
    if 'Punch' and 'bag' and '50kg' in x:
        count = count + 1
    print x
    print len(x)

print count
```

That is my current code with some troubleshooting extras. Takes three keywords and searches through the trademe website page html.

It iterates line by line through the html looking for the keywords, however it truncates at 128 characters and so break some lines apart, treating them as different lines.

So when I print 'x' I want to print the entire line (up to ~400 characters) rather than its 128 character fragment.

```
 Sample output:

e" src="http://images.trademe.co.nz/photoserver/lv2/94/201828294.jpg" alt="* No.1 Fitness * KANGO Black Punching Bag 50kg" align
128
ted">* No.1 Fitness * KANGO Black Punching Bag 50kg</a>
            <a id="ListView_CardRepeater_ctl06_card_GeneralCard_lis
128
2
```

This is the full line for the first instance:

```
                <a id="ListView_CardRepeater_ctl06_card_GeneralCard_listingImageLink" href="/sports/martial-arts-boxing/bags/auction-678639714.htm"><img id="ListView_CardRepeater_ctl06_card_GeneralCard_listingImage" src="http://images.trademe.co.nz/photoserver/lv2/94/201828294.jpg" alt="* No.1 Fitness * KANGO Black Punching Bag 50kg" align="middle" style="border-width:0px;" /></a>
```

This is the full line for the second:

```
            <a href="/sports/martial-arts-boxing/bags/auction-678639714.htm" id="ListView_CardRepeater_ctl06_card_GeneralCard_listingTitle" class="dotted">* No.1 Fitness * KANGO Black Punching Bag 50kg</a>
```

Comment: Show some code, with inputs and hoped-for outputs. Your English description is too vague to work with.

Comment: Can you show any code?

Comment: "it truncates at 128 characters and so break some lines apart, treating them as different lines" - you sure about that? I'm not seeing anything here that would cause that behavior. Can you show example output?

Comment: How are you running this script? What commands in what environment?

Comment: `if 'Punch' and 'bag' and '50kg' in x:` doesn't do what you think it does. Also, you'll have a much easier time if you us an HTML parser to properly extract information from the document.

Comment: I think it't because the code, but the terminal. Maybe you can output the result to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used a wrong iterator. It treats whole web page as a single string, and gives you 128 characters at a time. These are not actual lines present in the webpage.

Try this...

```
r = requests.get(<your url>)
for x in r.iter_lines():
    // do something...
```

Alternatively, you can do the same with urllib2 module.

```
import urllib2
...
r = urllib2.urlopen(<your url >)
for x in r:
    // do something...
```